# How to extract data from iterating a sequence

Tags: f#, seq

`csvData1` contains the data in a .csv file. I've created a sequence out of just two of the columns in the spreadsheet 
`("GIC-ID", "COVERAGE DESCRIPTION")`

```
let mappedSeq1 = 
   seq { for csvRow in csvData1 do yield (csvRow.[2], csvRow.[5]) }
```

Looking in the Visual Studio debugger `x` winds up being a `System.Tuple<string,string>`.

```
for x in mappedSeq1 do
    printfn "%A" x
    printfn "%A" x.ToString
```

Here is the result of executing

`for x in mappedSeq1`

```
("GIC-ID", "COVERAGE DESCRIPTION")
<fun:main@28>
```

I am having difficulty figuring out how to access `x`, so I can extract the first element.

Comment: You should be able to do `for (gicId, desc) in mappedSeq1 do...`

Comment: I think you're getting the <fun:main@28> because x.ToString means "the ToString function of x", probably you wanted to do x.ToString() with parentheses which means "execute the ToString function of x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pattern matching to deconstruct the tuple

```
for (a, b) in mappedSeq1 do
  // ...
```

or

```
for x in mappedSeq1 do
  let a, b = x
```

Alternatively for a 2-tuple you can use the built-in function `fst` and `snd`

Comment: @octopusgrabbus `x` shouldn't be a `seq` anyway but a 2-tuple (from the sample you gave) and so should work (or there are missing information in the question)

Comment: When I print out x, it's a function. I cannot use .fst, because it's not a method of the object.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus `x` isn't a function ; you think it is because of `printfn "%A" x.ToString`. `ToString` is a function and `ToString ()` (note the parens) is the result of calling that function. Also you don't "dot into" to use `fst` it's a "free function" and have to be used this way `let firstPart = fst x`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Seq.map` and `fst` to get a sequence of only the first component of a tuple:

```
let firstOnly = mappedSeq |> Seq.map fst
```

Comment: `Seq.map fst` is enough ;)

Comment: @Sehnsucht Thanks. Linq habits.

Comment: Cannot get this to work on the x in for x in mappedSeq1. It's a function.

Comment: If x is a function then this part of your question: `x` winds up being a System.Tuple<string,string>. is not correct. Please adjust the question.

Comment: Also, this syntax: `seq { for csvRow in csvData1 do yield (csvRow.[2], csvRow.[5]) }` will result in a sequence of tuples.

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski just nitpicking but in Linq it would be the same, you can use a method group when you have the pattern for example `Select (arg => fct (arg))` you can replace it by `Select (fct)`