# How to convert the x of for x in seq to seq

Tags: f#, seq, argument-unpacking

This is a follow-up question to this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477638/how-to-extract-data-from-iterating-a-sequence).

Given this block of code (csvData1 is a .csv file.)

```
let mappedSeq1 = seq { for csvRow in csvData1 do yield (csvRow.[2], csvRow.[5]) }

for x in mappedSeq1 do
    printfn "%A" x
```

What if I don't want to unpack each element of the sequence into `x` and a second val we could call `y`. How can I convert `x` to a sequence, so I can use `Seq.fst` and `Seq.snd`?

I know it is possible to unpack these elements. My question is about finding an alternate way to do this, especially given that `x` is a System.Tuple.

Comment: *"what is `x`?"* Are you using a development tool with type information? For example, in Visual Studio, you can see the type of `x` by hovering your mouse over it.

Comment: Yes, x is a System.Tuple, but I cannot structure the code to use Seq.fst and so on.

Comment: I've removed the What is x portion of the OP. Basically, I want to pull the first or second element from the System.Tuple without unpacking. It's more or less an academic request. I just want to know if there's another way.

Comment: You can use `fst` and `snd` instead of destructuring...

Comment: Call `fst x` or `snd x`. A tuple is not a `seq`, and `fst`/`snd` come from the `Operators` module. There's no `Seq.fst`, at least not one that does what you want.

Comment: That's it. I'm confusing the sequence with a tuple that was derived from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is a tuple of two `string`s (which is what I assume `csvRow.[i]` are), because that's how you `yield` it from the sequence. And you can destructure it right in your `for` loop:

```
for (x,y) in mappedSeq1 do
   printfn "%s - %s" x y
```

or you can use `fst x` or `snd x` if you do not want to destructure x.

Comment: I don't want to destructure x. For lack of a better way to describe it, I'd like to cast x to a Seq, so I can use Seq's methods.

Comment: I don't quite understand how you want to "cast x to Seq". `x` is a tuple, not a sequence, so you can't "cast it" to one. Did you mean that you wanted to _create_ a sequence with the two elements in it? Then you can just make a list `[x; y]`. Did you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently creates a sequence which reads rows and produces tuples of columns 2 and 5.

If you want to return a sequence of Row0Col2; Row0Col5; Row1Col2; Row1Col5 (the two columns will need to be of the same type), then use

`yield! [ csvRow.[2], csvRow.[5] ]`

Or if you want a sequence of sequences - [Row0Col2; Row0Col5]; [Row1Col2; Ro1Col5], then use

`yield [ csvRow.[2]; csvRow.[5] ]`

`yield!` will yield each individual item from the lists, whereas `yield` will just yield the lists in sequence.